# Cloud Run with Gunicorn Best-Practise

Tags: python, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I am currently working on a service that is supposed to provide an HTTP endpoint in Cloud Run and I don't have much experience. I am currently using flask + gunicorn and can also call the service. My main problem now is optimising for multiple simultaneous requests. Currently, the service in Cloud Run has 4GB of memory and 1 CPU allocated to it. When it is called once, the instance that is started directly consumes 3.7GB of memory and about 40-50% of the CPU (I use a neural network to embed my data). Currently, my settings are very basic:

- memory: 4096M
- CPU: 1
- min-instances: 0
- max-instances: 1
- concurrency: 80
- Workers: 1 (Gunicorn)
- Threads: 1 (Gunicorn)
- Timeout: 0 (Gunicorn, as recommended by Google)

If I up the number of workers to two, I would need to up the Memory to 8GB. If I do that my service should be able to work on two requests simultaneously with one instance, if this 1 CPU allocated, has more than one core. But what happens, if there is a thrid request? I would like to think, that Cloud Run will start a second instance. Does the new instance gets also 1 CPU and 8GB of memory and if not, what is the best practise for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best practice is to let Cloud Run scale automatically instead of trying to optimize each instance. Using 1 worker is a good idea to limit the memory footprint and reduce the cold start.

I recommend to play with the threads, typically to put it to 8 or 16 to leverage the concurrency parameter.

If you put those value too low, Cloud Run internal load balancer will route the request to the instance, thinking it will be able to serve it, but if Gunicorn can't access new request, you will have issues.

Tune your service with the correct parameter of CPU and memory, but also the thread and the concurrency to find the correct ones. [Hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey) is a useful tool to stress your service and observe what's happens when you scale.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So basically concurrency and gunicorn threads should always have the same value, so that one instance is always able to work on all requests that are allowed by the concurrency parameter, before Cloud Run starts a new instance?

Comment: Yes, I recommend to let the Cloud Run load balancer doing its own routing (and rate-limit) instead of doing it inside your service, because Cloud Run LB won't understand/detect nothing and you will have a lot of unserved requests

Comment: I got one last question because I can't find an answer online. If I set my thread parameter to two, start the container locally and send two async requests, both requests get servered at the same time, because my CPU has 8 Threads. When I select one CPU in Cloud Run do I get a "CPU" or only a thread on a CPU? So, would one Cloud Run instance be able to work on both threads at the same time or would the second thread only take the request and wait until the first thread has finished, when CPU is set to 1?

Comment: Interesting question. CPU on Google Cloud have only 1 thread (in case of HT CPU), it's named vCPU and not CPU because of that. If you prefer, you have a compute power of 2Ghz+ dedicated to you. Then, how work a CPU. In front of the compute unit, you have an orchestrator. When compute power is required, the orchestrator load and process the task, then release it and go to the next one. The orchestrator has no conscious of a "request". If your request perform and API call and wait for a response, the CPU is not used and the orchestrator loads another task into the CPU registries.

Comment: Like that, you can process several request in the same time. In addition the orchestrator doesn't allow indefinitively CPU to 1 task, it's for a while, then, another task is load, and the previous one put to the queue and wait his turn to continue the processing. It's named concurrent execution (because it's not parallel)

Comment: On my PC I cut the time it takes for two requests in half, if I set threads = 2. In Cloud Run it still get a performance gain, but not by the factor 2. Can you tell me why that happens or why I get a performance gain at all, when my CPU parameter in Cloud Run is set to 1 and I only have one thread availabe within my container? (max_instances is set to 1).

Answer (score 0):

The best practice so far is For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers to be equal to the cores available. Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling. Adjust the number of workers and threads on a per-application basis. For example, try to use a number of workers equal to the cores available and make sure there is a performance improvement, then adjust the number of threads.i.e.

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```